# Fixing sloping hardwood floor in rental apartment

Tags: repair, hardwood-floor, hardwood, slope

I just moved into a rental apartment in the top floor of a 1900 building with a very old hardwood floor.  The floor looks attractive, except the whole room is on a slant.  I estimate that one side of the floor is at least 1-2 inches below the opposite side.  Plus, it's not a clear downward slope -- it seems to go inward toward the center of one of the walls from all other sides of the room.

I can put levelers under my bed frame and some other furniture, but it's really uncomfortable to sit at my office desk/chair to do work from home.  And since I need the office chair to roll in/out, I can't just put levelers under it.

The problem is that this is a rental apartment and I doubt the landlord will allow me to re-do the old flooring.  Is there any way to fix this just for the 1-2 years that I live there?  Even if I only fixed this for a 4 ft. by 4 ft. section of the floor so that I could put my office/desk over level ground, I'd be happy.

I was thinking about applying some kind of lightweight concrete leveler to a mold made out of large plank of plastic/wood/something else and somehow keeping it from spilling out onto my actual floor.  I would put a carpet over the slab of concrete and put my chair/desk over it. I'd want the slab of self-leveled cement to be removable, such that I could get rid of it without damaging the hardwood floor when I move out.

Is there any way to make this work?  Or does anyone have a better idea that is more feasible?

Comment: Can you just make something like a 4'x8' platform from common 2x4s and plywood or would that end up being too thick for you (at least 4" thick, not including leveling)?

Comment: No need to use full lumber. A 3/4" deck with tapered "joists" would level things out and would be no more than about 1-1/2" high at the low end. A small lip would keep chairs from rolling off.

Comment: The self-leveling material is a good idea, though. A simple tapered frame with a polyethylene liner would do.

Comment: Thanks, everyone!  I really appreciate the helpful tips.